# set backlight time

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there any way to change backlight turn off TIME using programming(Preferred  c# or vb.net other c++ can be used too)? I guess, may be it is changed using registry info or API.

Manually, it is done by:

Setting > Backlight (Battery Power and External Power)

Thank you

Comment: In the future, if you suspect something is done through the registry you can do the following: take a snapshot of the registry before the operation, do the change, take another snapshot of the registry and then compare them to find what to change. you can use http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/ as the registry editor. It is an excellent registry editor for ActiveSync devices.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the following registry keys (which is what the CPL does):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Backlight]`
    "UseBattery"=dword        ;if '1' turn off the backligh after "BatteryTimeout" seconds
    "UseExt"=dword:           ;if '1' turn off the backligh after "ACTimeout" seconds
    "BatteryTimeout"=dword:X  ;backlight timeout in seconds 
    "ACTimeout"=dword:Y       ;backlight timeout in seconds
```

Then broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message.

Answer (score 0):

`::SystemParametersInfo` does it.
Specify `uiAction` parameter to `SPI_SETBATTERYIDLETIMEOUT` to adjust "battery timeout" and/or `SPI_SETEXTERNALIDLETIMEOUT` for "AC timeout".

See detailed information on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee499131(v=winembedded.60).aspx).